# Ordered XPath values separated by a semicolon

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I have the following XML file:

```
<Body>
    <ELEMENT Property1="A" Property2="B" Property3="C"/>
    <ELEMENT Property1="D" Property2="E" Property3="F"/>
    <ELEMENT Property1="G" Property2="H" Property3="I"/>
</Body>
```

And I'm trying to have a one string object all of the properties values ordered like this:

> A,B,C;D,E,F;G,H,I

I basically need to have each ELEMENT properties seperated by a semicolon.

How to do that?

Comment: Show what have you tried

Comment: @Andersson To be frank, I couldn't think of any possible expression...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I wanted `,` between the properties and `;` between the ELEMENTs, here's the required solution for an undefined number of ELEMENTs :

`string-join(for $x in //ELEMENT return string-join($x/@*,','), ';')`

The result is

> A,B,C;D,E,F;G,H,I

Answer (score 1):

You can try below expression

```
string-join((string-join(//ELEMENT/@Property1, ','), string-join(//ELEMENT/@Property2, ','), string-join(//ELEMENT/@Property3, ',')), ';')
```

Output:

```
A,D,G;B,E,H;C,F,I
```

or

```
string-join((string-join(//ELEMENT[1]/@*, ','), string-join(//ELEMENT[2]/@*, ','), string-join(//ELEMENT[3]/@*, ',')), ';')
```

output:

```
A,B,C;D,E,F;G,H,I
```

Comment: I actually made a mistake, sorry for that.
The expected result is `A,B,C;D,E,F;G,H,I`.

One element at a time.

Comment: Excellent ! Thank you :)

One more thing please, what if the number of ELEMENT was unexpected ? is there a way to iterate ?

Comment: Note, attributes in XML have no intrinsic ordering, so the order of attributes delivered by "@*" is unpredictable. There is no way of ensuring that the output contains "A,B,C" rather than "C,A,B" unless you work with the actual property names.

Comment: @Radhwen, I'm not sure it can be done with `XPath` only. I guess you can use the features of the tool you use to make a loop through all `ELEMENT` nodes

Comment: @Andersson Something like `string-join((string-join(//ELEMENT[position()>0]/@*, ',')), ';')` could solve the issue. But it's just that there will be no more semicolon between the elements. Here's the result :

 A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I

Comment: If you want to get properties separated with comma, you can simply use `string-join(//ELEMENT/@*, ',')`

Comment: I actually wanted `,` between the properties and `;` between the ELEMENT. Here's the required solution for an undefined number of ELEMENT : `string-join(for $x in //ELEMENT return string-join($x/@*,','), ';')`